# Export PDF in Laravel with so much data

Tags: php, laravel, export, export-to-pdf

I have the next code

```
$html = '';
foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $html .= '<div class="table-scrollable">
                        <table id="posts" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="body"><tr>
                                <td>'
                . $post->id . ' 
                                </td>
                                <td>' .
                $post->name .
                '</td>
                                <td>'
                . $post->title .
                '</td> 
                    </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>';
}
return PDF::load($html, 'A4', 'portrait')->download('my_pdf');
```

The problem is when I want to download so much data i'm getting the next error `The localhost page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request.` But if I try to download for example 20 entry, works fine. What can I do?

laravel.log

> [2016-11-24 13:15:17] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException'
>   with message 'Undefined variable: data_start' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/app/controllers/IncasariController.php:58
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/app/controllers/IncasariController.php(58):
>
> Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...',
>   '/Applications/X...', 58, Array)
>
> ## 1 [internal function]: IncasariController->filtrareChitante()
>
> ## 2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(231):
>
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> ## 3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(93):
>
> Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('filtrareChitant...', Array)
>
> ## 4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(62):
>
> Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(IncasariController),
>   Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'filtrareChitant...')
>
> ## 5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(962):
>
> Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route),
>   Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'IncasariControl...',
>   'filtrareChitant...')
>
> ## 6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}()
>
> ## 7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(109):
>
> call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
>
> ## 8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1028):
>
> Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> ## 9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996):
>
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> ## 10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775):
>
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> ## 11 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745):
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> ## 12 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72):
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
>   1, true)
>
> ## 13 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47):
>
> Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
>   1, true)
>
> ## 14 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51):
>
> Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1,
>   true)
>
> ## 15 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23):
>
> Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1,
>   true)
>
> ## 16 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641):
>
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> ## 17 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
>
> ## 18 {main} [] []

And on webpage is:

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
```

Comment: please give us more information about software that you're using (xampp? Mac? Linux?), what package you currently use for PDF

Comment: Please post some log entries like in laravel.log or in apache / nginx error.log

Comment: @ImamAssidiqqi I'm using XAMPP. This is the package i'm using: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.4

Comment: That error is indication an issue elsewhere - run  composer install, composer dump-autoload

Comment: @JonC runned ..but nothing happens :(

Comment: Your log is telling you you have undefined data in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dicom/app/controllers/IncasariController.php on line 58. post the code for this file

Comment: The problem from line 58 was solved, but the problem with PDF not:(

Comment: so maybe provide  the log entry for the pdf issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is assuming that every record has an ID, name and a title.

I would check to see if these are actually set before calling them

Something like this.

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {

$id= isset($post->id) ? $post->id : 'ID Not Set';
$name= isset($post->name) ? $post->name : 'Name Not Set';
$title= isset($post->title) ? $post->title : ' Title Not Set';

    $html .= '<div class="table-scrollable">
                    <table id="posts" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Title</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="body">
                          <tr>
                            <td>'. $id .'</td>
                            <td>'. $name .'</td>
                            <td>'. $title .'</td> 
                          </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>';
}
```

If they are not set they could cause your code to fail with and Object not found error.

You can check your logs from storage/logs folder

Comment: Note: since PHP 7.0 it's possible to add `$id ?? '';` This will check if the $id is set, if this is the case it will set the variable. If the variable is not set, it will take the given variable, in this case an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you try to export large datasets into PDF. My advice :

1. Try to make custom CSS to reduce pages load ( you can copy paste your classes to your custom CSS )
2. Change max execution time on *php.ini* on your XAMPP (1 minute, 5 minutes, 10 minutes, etc)